# I'm trying to clone objects in unity3d but getting two errors.

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

The goal is using this script to clone gameobjects in random: places,heights,sizes in the terrain area.

In the editor in the scene i added a new empty gameobject and renamed it to: ObjectToClone

Then i added two new tags: Terrain and ObjectToClone
Tagged ObjectToClone with the tag ObjectToClone and tagged Terrain with the tag Terrain.

Dragged the script to the ObjectToClone gameobject and in the Inspector in the script added the ObjectToClone

```
using System;
using UnityEngine;
using Random = UnityEngine.Random;
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;

public class CloneObjects : MonoBehaviour
{

    public GameObject ObjectToClone;
    public int objectsStartingHeight = 20;
    [HideInInspector]
    public GameObject[] clonedObjects;

    // for tracking properties change
    private Vector3 _extents;
    private int _objectCount;
    private float _objectSize;
    private List<int> randomNumbers = new List<int>();

    /// <summary>
    ///     How far to place spheres randomly.
    /// </summary>
    public Vector3 Extents;

    /// <summary>
    ///     How many spheres wanted.
    /// </summary>
    public int ObjectCount;
    public float ObjectSize;

    // Use this for initialization
    void Start()
    {

        rndNumbers();
        Clone();
        clonedObjects = GameObject.FindGameObjectsWithTag("ObjectToClone");
    }

    private void OnValidate()
    {
        // prevent wrong values to be entered
        Extents = new Vector3(Mathf.Max(0.0f, Extents.x), Mathf.Max(0.0f, Extents.y), Mathf.Max(0.0f, Extents.z));
        ObjectCount = Mathf.Max(0, ObjectCount);
        ObjectSize = Mathf.Max(0.0f, ObjectSize);
    }

    private void Reset()
    {
        Extents = new Vector3(250.0f, 20.0f, 250.0f);
        ObjectCount = 100;
        ObjectSize = 20.0f;
    }

    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update()
    {

    }

    private void Clone()
    {
        if (Extents == _extents && ObjectCount == _objectCount && Mathf.Approximately(ObjectSize, _objectSize))
            return;

        // cleanup
        var ShipsToDestroy = GameObject.FindGameObjectsWithTag("ObjectToClone");
        foreach (var t in ShipsToDestroy)
        {
            if (Application.isEditor)
            {
                DestroyImmediate(t);
            }
            else
            {
                Destroy(t);
            }
        }

        var withTag = GameObject.FindWithTag("Terrain");
        if (withTag == null)
            throw new InvalidOperationException("Terrain not found");

        for (var i = 0; i < ObjectCount; i++)
        {
            var o = Instantiate(ObjectToClone);
            o.tag = "Cube";
            o.transform.SetParent(base.gameObject.transform);
            o.transform.localScale = new Vector3(ObjectSize, ObjectSize, ObjectSize);

            // get random position
            var x = Random.Range(-Extents.x, Extents.x);
            var y = Extents.y; // sphere altitude relative to terrain below
            var z = Random.Range(-Extents.z, Extents.z);

            // now send a ray down terrain to adjust Y according terrain below
            var height = 10000.0f; // should be higher than highest terrain altitude
            var origin = new Vector3(x, height, z);
            var ray = new Ray(origin, Vector3.down);
            RaycastHit hit;
            var maxDistance = 20000.0f;
            var nameToLayer = LayerMask.NameToLayer("Terrain");
            var layerMask = 1 << nameToLayer;
            if (Physics.Raycast(ray, out hit, maxDistance, layerMask))
            {
                var distance = hit.distance;
                y = height - distance + y; // adjust
            }
            else
            {
                Debug.LogWarning("Terrain not hit, using default height !");
            }

            //o.transform.Rotate(0.0f,randomNumbers[i],0.0f);
            // place !
            o.transform.position = new Vector3(x, y + objectsStartingHeight, z);
        }

        _extents = Extents;
        _objectCount = ObjectCount;
        _objectSize = ObjectSize;
    }

    public void rndNumbers()
    {

    }
}
```

The errors i'm getting the first one

Assertion failed on expression: 'm_InstanceID != InstanceID_None'
0x000000014151284B (Unity) StackWalker::GetCurrentCallstack

And

MissingReferenceException: The object of type 'GameObject' has been destroyed but you are still trying to access it.
Your script should either check if it is null or you should not destroy the object.

If i'm not destroying it will create many objects even if i set a number of objects to clone.

Comment: it's obvious that you are destroying the game object just before instantiating from it.

Comment: Are you sure you are instantiating a prefab? It seems like you are trying to instantiate a gameobject